# File renameTo does not work

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am trying to add an extension to the name of file selected by a `JFileChooser` although I can't get it to work.

This is the code :

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
            String name =f.getAbsoluteFile()+".txt";
            f.renameTo(new File(name));
            FileWriter fstream;
            try {
                fstream = new FileWriter(f);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                out.write("test one");
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AppCore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I also tried using getPath() and getCanonicalPath() but the result is the same. The file is created at the directory selected, although without a ".txt" extension.

Comment: have you checked the result from `renameTo`? This is from the Java documentation "Whether or not this method can move a file from one filesystem to another is platform-dependent. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful."

Comment: Yes its always returning false. The only time it worked is when I set the new File name manually but without including the path : "test.txt". That created a txt containing "test one" but not at the selected directory

Comment: Are you sure the target file doesn't already exist?

Comment: Yes. A new file is created but without extension. I just do the test on desktop so I can see whats happening.

Comment: Can you create a file just using `File f2 = new File(name);`?

Comment: LoL yes that actually worked... Should have though about trying..
Guess I can go with that but any guess why renameTo doesn't work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me that all you want to do is to change the *name* of the file chosen, as opposed to renaming a file on the filesystem.  In that case, you don't use `File.renameTo`. You just change the `File`.  Something like the following should work:

```
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String name = f.getAbsoluteFile()+".txt";
        f = new File(name);
```

[`File.renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) attempts to rename a file on the filesystem.  For example:

```
File oldFile = new File("test1.txt");
File newFile = new File("test2.txt");
boolean success = oldFile.renameTo(newFile); // renames test1.txt to test2.txt
```

After these three lines, `success` will be `true` if the file `test1.txt` could be renamed to `test2.txt`, and `false` if the rename was unsuccessful (e.g. `test1.txt` doesn't exist, is open in another process, permission was denied, etc.)

I will hazard a guess that the renaming you are attempting is failing because you are attempting to rename a directory (you are using a `JFileChooser` with the `DIRECTORIES_ONLY` option). If you have programs using files within this directory, or a Command Prompt open inside it, they will object to this directory being renamed.

Comment: Yes you are right I ended up just creating a new File using the name(directory) from the Chooser. I just thought the renameTo was an operation that could be used in this case.

Comment: In my case, the BufferedReader was open. For this reason the file can't be renamed.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [`Files.move`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#move%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) utility from Google Guava libraries to rename a file. Its easier than writing your own method.

From the docs:

> Moves the file from one path to another. This method can rename a file or move it to a different directory, like the Unix mv command.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing to the wrong file. When you call renameTo, the current file doesn't change it's path. Try this:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String name =f.getAbsoluteFile()+".txt";
        File f2 = new File(name);
        f.renameTo(f2);
        FileWriter fstream;
        try {
            fstream = new FileWriter(f2);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write("test one");
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AppCore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well this doesn't really make any use of the renameTo method. Although it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Rename the file then there is must to close all the object (like FileReader,FileWriter ,FIS ,FOSmeans close the the reading file object and then rename it

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance to refer to the new name of the file

```
oldFile = new File(newName);
```